# how to use temporary registers - are values preserved after return?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am writing a program in MIPS assembly using the MARS simulator.  I'm using `jal` to make a function call, then using `jr $ra` at the end of that to return to the original point in the program.

What I'm confused about is that the `$t` registers that I've used in my function still have the values in them after returning to the main program.

Should I be zeroing these registers out before returning so that future functions using the temporary registers can start with a clean slate?  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm confused about is that the $t registers that I've used in my function still have the values in them after returning to the main program.

Yes, just like all the other registers have the same values (nothing special happens just because you return from your function).

> Should I be zeroing these registers out before returning so that future functions using the temporary registers can start with a clean slate? Am I missing something here?

No need to zero them, they were there for you to use! You're free to do whatever you like with the temporary registers, just keep in mind that if you call another function (or your own!) that they'll do the same thing, so you can't depend on the values across function calls. Contrast this with the `$s` registers that you need to save and restore if you modify, but you can (usually) depend on other functions doing the same thing for you. This is part of the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS).

Comment: "Should I be zeroing these registers out before returning so that future functions using the temporary registers can start with a clean slate?"  No. Also you should note that the temporary registers have unknown state when your function is called, they will not often contain zeroes.